# How do I install sfml-audio to build extreme tux racer?

Tags: linux-mint, compiling, dependencies, configure

I have downloaded extreme tux racer as a .tar.xz on sourceforge.
I performed `tar xJF` on the file, a directory was created, I entered it and there I performed `./configure`. A list of Dependencies was displayed telling whether or not it was installed:

```
 ikigai@ikigai-SATELLITE-L50D-B ~/Downloads/etr-0.7.1 $ ./configure
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking for g++... g++
checking whether the C++ compiler works... yes
checking for C++ compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of g++... gcc3
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking float.h usability... yes
checking float.h presence... yes
checking for float.h... yes
checking limits.h usability... yes
checking limits.h presence... yes
checking for limits.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
checking for string.h... (cached) yes
checking sys/time.h usability... yes
checking sys/time.h presence... yes
checking for sys/time.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes
checking for stdbool.h that conforms to C99... yes
checking for _Bool... yes
checking for inline... inline
checking for size_t... yes
checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
checking for GNU libc compatible malloc... yes
checking for floor... no
checking for getcwd... yes
checking for memmove... yes
checking for memset... yes
checking for mkdir... yes
checking for pow... no
checking for sqrt... no
checking for strchr... yes
checking for strdup... yes
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for SFML_AUDIO... no
configure: error: sfml-audio not found
```

I have intuitevily tried `sudo apt-get install floor`  to install one of the dependencies checked as no, but I guess it does not make much sense, nethertheless is so far the only way I know, how can I change from no to yes ?

Regarding the question of whether I have libc6-dev installed,
I performed `ldconfig -p | grep libc6-dev` without any result, but when I perform `ldconfig -p | grep libc6` there are a lot of lines containing this string displayed.

I opened the package manager, but when I entered the term `sfml` I got about 30 different lines, for `sfml-audio` about 10. I do not know how to choose the right thing.

I use Linux Mint 17.3 Rosa.

Comment: You should expect to see a bunch of 'no's - focus on the actual errors (i.e. in this case, `error: sfml-audio not found`

Comment: `floor` and the other mathematical functions are part of *libc*. Take a look if `/usr/include/math.h` and the files included from it are available; if not you're perhaps missing the related development package, which contains the headers.

Comment: do you have libc6-dev installed?

Comment: i performed   ldconfig -p | grep libc6-dev   without any result, does it mean it is not installed ?

Comment: but when i perform   ldconfig -p | grep libc6  there are a lot of lines containing this string displayed

Comment: @murphy I opened /usr/include/math.h  but frankly speaking i do not know how to read this file, it looks like C to me which I do not speak,  what should I look for in it ?

Comment: Forget that suggestion if you don't know how to read header files. @steeldriver has the big picture right, ignore the no's if they don't lead to an error. RuiFRibeiro's suggestion is correct if you want to solve that nevertheless. Use your package manager to search for that package, and to install the SFML libs, too.

Comment: opened the package manager, but when I entered the term "sfml" i got about 30 different lines, for "sfml-audio" about 10 , do not know how to choose the right thing.

Comment: Start by telling us what type/flavor/distribution of Unix or Linux you are running - they don't all package development files the same way. FWIW I suspect the math tests are just checking whether your particular flavor of *nix links libm by default, so that it knows whether it needs to add `-lm` in the Makefiles that it generates.

Comment: lsb_release -a  shows:

Comment: No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: LinuxMint
Description: Linux Mint 17.3 Rosa
Release: 17.3
Codename: rosa

Comment: BTW, as educational as building a package from source may be, but if you just want to play Tuxracer why don't you install the binary package? The package manager would also solve the dependencies for you... Or is the version you want not available for your distribution?

Comment: indeed, it is all about understanding how the routine of building a package from source works in practice, i ve just chosen tux because it looks cute.

Comment: Allright, go on ;-) Regarding your results when searching the ld cache for *libc6*: While *libc6* is an actual library, *libc6-dev*, or whatever it may be named on Mint, is a supplementary package containing the "development files" (usually the headers and some developer-related docs); the linker doesn't know anything about that. You need that to compile dependent packages from source. And as Tuxracer seems to depend on SFML libs, you'll need to install the lib and its dev files, too, in order to compile.

Comment: Based on what I see on Ubuntu 14.04, you'll want `libsfml-dev`, plus `libcsfml-dev` if you need the C bindings

Answer (score 0):

In the output of `configure`, don't worry about “no”. That just indicates that a certain feature is not present, but the job of `configure` is to detect which features are present on your system and which ones are not and to adapt the compile-time configuration of the software accordingly.

If a mandatory feature is not present, `configure` tells you that there is an error. Here you do have an error:

> ```
> configure: error: sfml-audio not found
> ```

You need to install the corresponding tools. When compiling software, you need the right development packages. Under Debian and derivatives, including Linux Mint, the convention for development packages is that their name ends with `-dev`. To run the software, you'll need the corresponding dynamic library package. Looking at Debian's file list (`apt-file search sfml-audio`), it looks like what you need at compile-time is `libsfml-dev`. Installing the development packages also installs the right runtime libraries (here `libsfml-audio2`).

Once you've installed the necessary dependency, run `./configure` again.